# Programmatically add a new dynamic order to a cart in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I want to be able to create a dynamic order and add it to the shopping cart. Today at the moment I add a new order to my cart by doing the following ajax:

```
 jQuery.get('?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function(response) {
             // call back
            // alert(response);
});
```

The problem with this approach is i have to supply a product id which represents a product I have added to the Woocommerce backend.

I want to be able to calculate at runtime the cost and and simply use woocommerce to complete the checkout process and track the customer data. This is for a class booking system where users opt into various different sessions on different dates which is why the static product example doesnt quite fit.

Is there an API / example of doing something like this where I can supply the cost of my product dynamically to woocommerce and have it handle the rest of the checkout process as it normally does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to add something to the cart where a product does not exist.

My suggestion would be to use a 'Name Your Price' extension and create a product.  Then you can pass the price in as an argument to the add-to-cart call.  ex:

`'?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id + '&price=' + price`

Few options:

http://www.woothemes.com/products/name-your-price/

http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-pay-your-price/7000238

http://wordpress.org/plugins/shatner-name-your-own-price-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Fanatastic didnt know this existed!